# XCTest : Not able to delete user default data of framework target

Tags: ios, swift2, nsuserdefaults, xctest

Target is iOS8 dynamic framework(UserDataFramework) and I saved a data on UserData class. Now removing the saved data for checking as App-Delete-Scenario. But not able to delete data from testTarget (UserDataFrameworkTest) to framework data (UserDataFramework).

```
import XCTest
@testable import UserDataFramework
func testAppDeleteFunctionality() {
     UserData.saveData()
     let kCheckFirstRun = "com.key.checkFirstRun"

     // When app deleted, cleared the user default
     let userDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
     userDefault.removeObjectForKey(kCheckFirstRun)
     userDefault.synchronize()
     let checkData = userDefault.valueForKey(kCheckFirstRun)
     XCTAssertNil(checkData)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem due to switching simulators from iOS 9 to iOS 10. I found this bug from Apple side. Just restart the system and userdefault can delete and store value as well.